# How to add placeholder or 0 to Blazor Date

Tags: c#, html, blazor, blazor-client-side, asp.net-blazor

```
<InputDate id="birthday" class="form-control"   placeholder=@Loc["birthday"] @bind-Value="PersModel.Pers.GeburtsDatum" />

public DateTime GeburtsDatum { get; set; }
```

I want the Default value to be any placeholder or Nothing only when date selected to be changed

[image: i want the Default value to be any placeholder or Nothing only when date selected to be changed]

```
 pers.GeburtsDatumString = pers.GeburtsDatum.ToString("dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

whenever i Change the

```
public DateTime? GeburtsDatum { get; set; }  to be able to be 0 i get error at 


pers.GeburtsDatumString = pers.GeburtsDatum.ToString("dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[image: error here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [null-conditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) operator to handle nullable DateTime:

```
pers.GeburtsDatumString = pers.GeburtsDatum?.ToString("dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
//                                         ^
```

This returns `null` when `pers.GeburtsDatum.HasValue` is false (ie, when the value is null).

Answer (score 0):

nullable Date type requires .value
pers.GeburtsDatum.Value